# I have a .net6 API Windows Service listening to some ports. I have binded on OS level an SSL certificate, but on browser i see localhost Certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, .net-6.0

Like the title says, the service is running, listening to https endpoints on

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "https://*:5400"
      }
    }
  },
```

on netSh i have binded the port to an existing ssl cert

```
    IP:port                      : 0.0.0.0:5400
    Certificate Hash             : 80609affff00cacdff26b3c0a61e2e5695265b94
    Application ID               : {f80f71f6-e2e6-4ec5-b57c-c77783c022db}
    Certificate Store Name       : MY
    Verify Client Certificate Revocation : Enabled
    Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only : Disabled
    Usage Check                  : Enabled
    Revocation Freshness Time    : 0
    URL Retrieval Timeout        : 0
    Ctl Identifier               : (null)
    Ctl Store Name               : (null)
    DS Mapper Usage              : Disabled
    Negotiate Client Certificate : Disabled
    Reject Connections           : Disabled
    Disable HTTP2                : Not Set
    Disable QUIC                 : Not Set
    Disable TLS1.2               : Not Set
    Disable TLS1.3               : Not Set
    Disable OCSP Stapling        : Not Set
    Disable Legacy TLS Versions  : Not Set
```

My program.cs looks like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public const string ServiceName = "FlowsterEventService";
    public class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        
        public Service(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            ServiceName = Program.ServiceName;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            Log.Information("Creating builder");

            if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                Log.Information("Hosting windows Service(Production)");
                builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Information("Creating host builder (Developer Mode)");
                CreateHostBuilder(args);

            }
            builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
            {
                Log.Information($"{DateTime.Now} Configuring Kestrel");
                serverOptions.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(listenOption =>
                {
                    Log.Information("Configuring Kestrel -- ConfigureEndpointDefaults");
                });
            });
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration);

            builder.Services.AddWindowsService();

            Log.Information("Building App");
            var app = builder.Build();

            var loggerFactory = app.Services.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
            loggerFactory.AddFile(builder.Configuration["BaseLogging:LogPath"].ToString());

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                Log.Information("Configuring swagger");
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");
            app.MapControllers();
            //app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
            Log.Information("Running App");
            app.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Log.Fatal(ex, "The application failed to start correctly.");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog()
        .UseUrls("https://127.0.0.1:5400");

}
```

but when i try to acess the endpoint in the browser, i see a localhost default certificate, not the correct one as netsh shows me.

[Certificate on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExFvo.png)

Any ideas on what im doing wrong, or anything at all would be appreciated.

Note: Adding the certificate path on settings or in-code is not an option since my clients can change the certificate to their own.